# How to display "My Computer" icon on a Windows 10 desktop?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-icons

I just installed Windows 10 on my PC, but I didn't find any way to set "My Computer" icon to show on my desktop. How can I place it on my desktop?

Comment: Is it not the same as Windows 8: Right click desktop -> personalise -> desktop icons?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Press <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

then type:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,Web,0
```

to open the `Desktop Icons Settings` and tick `Computer`

and even easier:

Press <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

click `Personalization`, `Themes` and `Desktop icon settings`

[image]

Comment: @PeterHandorf is there some way to pin Computer and Recycling Bin to the top left when you have 'auto arrange icons' checked? Auto arrange keeps arranging things alphabetically.